# Auto Login With Python Request

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I have simple code for auto login using `request.session()` python

**My Issue**

have an issue while run the program appear result like this below:

> `< meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=http://website(dot)com/'>`

**My Code**

```
import requests

login_data = {
'token': 8873,
'user': 'username123',
'pass': 11228123,
'login': 'login'}

headers = {
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "http://website(dot)com/login/login.html"
    p = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
    print(p.content)
```

Comment: Have you tried doing same POST request by other programs? E.g. by CURL. So to be sure that requests is doing something wrong. Maybe it is website that answers a bad thing? Maybe you also tried some other websites to login with similar code?

Comment: Also would be great if you provide us with some real website that doesn't work. Maybe not yours by some other that has similar login steps. So that we can try running code and fixing on our side.

Comment: What is status code of answer (`p.status_code`)?

Comment: Also you may insert line `p.raise_for_status()` after `s.post(...)` line. This will control server errors. By default all server errors (non-200 http code) are not controlled by `requests` library.